# Can you Serialize the iframe tag to binary data Using protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

```
syntax = "proto2";
option java_outer_classname = "OpenRtb";
package com.google.openrtb;
message Person {
required string name = 1;
required int32 id = 2;
repeated Phone number = 3;
}
message Phone{
    required string id = 5;

}
```

protoc proto to python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: person.proto

import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='person.proto',
  package='com.google.openrtb',
  syntax='proto2',
  serialized_options=_b('B\007OpenRtb'),
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x0cperson.proto\x12\x12\x63om.google.openrtb\"M\n\x06Person\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x02(\t\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x02 \x02(\x05\x12)\n\x06number\x18\x03 \x03(\x0b\x32\x19.com.google.openrtb.Phone\"\x13\n\x05Phone\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x05 \x02(\tB\tB\x07OpenRtb')
)




_PERSON = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Person',
  full_name='com.google.openrtb.Person',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='name', full_name='com.google.openrtb.Person.name', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='id', full_name='com.google.openrtb.Person.id', index=1,
      number=2, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=0,
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='number', full_name='com.google.openrtb.Person.number', index=2,
      number=3, type=11, cpp_type=10, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=36,
  serialized_end=113,
)


_PHONE = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='Phone',
  full_name='com.google.openrtb.Phone',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  fields=[
    _descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='id', full_name='com.google.openrtb.Phone.id', index=0,
      number=5, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=2,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=_b("").decode('utf-8'),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      serialized_options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
  ],
  extensions=[
  ],
  nested_types=[],
  enum_types=[
  ],
  serialized_options=None,
  is_extendable=False,
  syntax='proto2',
  extension_ranges=[],
  oneofs=[
  ],
  serialized_start=115,
  serialized_end=134,
)

_PERSON.fields_by_name['number'].message_type = _PHONE
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Person'] = _PERSON
DESCRIPTOR.message_types_by_name['Phone'] = _PHONE
_sym_db.RegisterFileDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR)

Person = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Person', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _PERSON,
  __module__ = 'person_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:com.google.openrtb.Person)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Person)

Phone = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('Phone', (_message.Message,), dict(
  DESCRIPTOR = _PHONE,
  __module__ = 'person_pb2'
  # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:com.google.openrtb.Phone)
  ))
_sym_db.RegisterMessage(Phone)


DESCRIPTOR._options = None
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
bidResponse.id = 123
bid_resp_bid = bidResponse.number.add()
bid_resp_bid.id = 'zhehsi'
p1 = bidResponse.SerializeToString()
print(p1)
## the result(binary data) like this :
b'\nG<iframe  src="%%%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%https://play.google.com"></iframe>\x10\xc0\xc4\x07\x1a\x08*\x06zhehsi'



bid_esponse = person_pb2.Person()
bid_esponse.ParseFromString(p1)
p2 = json_format.MessageToDict(bid_esponse)
## parse the result(binary data) get:
{'name': '<iframe  src="%%%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%https://play.google.com"></iframe>', 'id': 123456, 'number': [{'id': 'zhehsi'}]}
```

as you see ,string" https://play.google.com">" is not be Serialized to   binary .
It is not changed.But I parse it ,it is right . However google support team said i am wrong.the "iframe tag" must be Serialized to   binary,if 
not they can not parse it. I do not know where i wrong.Can you check my code where is wrong? or can you
 Serialize the string("https://play.google.com">") to binary data?
how to  Serialize the iframe tag to binary data Using protbuf ?

Comment: the html code is  hidden by the stackoverflow page. it is not safe if the input is Code injection 。”as you see ,string" https://play.google.com">" is not be Serialized to binary .“ means "  as you see ,string" \<\iframe  src=\"%%%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%https://play.google.com"><\/iframe\>" is not be Serialized to   binary .  "
"or can you
Serialize the string("https://play.google.com">") to binary data?"  means "  or can you   
 Serialize the string("\<\iframe  src="%%%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%https://play.google.com">\<\/iframe\>") to binary data? "